# Adding parameters to start an application in OSX

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player, parameters

I'm trying to start my VLC-player on OSX with the following parameters:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --rtsp-timeout=99999 --sout-ffmpeg-strict=-2 --extraintf http --http-port=8081
```

Where do I have to put this code? I tried to create a new application with Automator, but it didn't work.

Comment: Parameter `---extraintf` should be `--extraintf`. I corrected the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In conjunction with cathalog's answer, in Terminal you can create an executable.

Open Terminal, type `cd Desktop` so the executable is saved to the Desktop, then type `nano "VLC"` or whatever name you want. You'll have a window to enter the command:

```
open /Applications/VLC.app/ --args --rtsp-timeout=99999 --sout-ffmpeg-strict=-2 --extraintf http --http-port=8081
```

To save the command, hit Control-X on your keyboard, then `Y` for yes to save it. There is now a file saved to your Desktop, but it can't run yet. Next, in Terminal type in `chmod +x "VLC"` or, again whatever you named it in the quotation marks. Then you've got a shortcut to run VLC with arguments!

Here's a [YouTube video](http://youtu.be/eodhTGDzkVI) with a step-by-step demonstration showing how to create an executable file in Terminal on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can open an app with arguments using a Terminal window.

Use the command `open /Applications/<NameOfApp.app> --args <your arguments here>`.

So, to start VLC player with the arguments you provided above, run this command:

```
open /Applications/VLC.app/ --args --rtsp-timeout=99999 --sout-ffmpeg-strict=-2 --extraintf http --http-port=8081
```

(Note that your flag `---extraintf`should be `--extraintf`)

Comment: Good for single use. OP wants a permanent solution, I guess.